# How to convert Azure Service Configuration file to base 64

Tags: azure

When creating a deployment in Azure Cloud through REST API, I need to encode Service Configuration file to base 64 string. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

How about the following line of code?

```
Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configurationFileContent));
```

Comment: It's done. I used FileStream to read the file and the create a Byte array. Then encode it in to Base 64 String.
Anyway thanks...